# How to encrypt password so as to prevent any sql injection scenario?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My SQL management studio is not working so I am making a login form using static list. I want to store username and password in the list and then compare them with existing entries in the list.Now I want to store my password as ****** not as text.Currently I am just inserting data from textbox to list, but I want to retrieve data from textbox and then encrypt it and then add it to the list.

Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridView
{
public partial class practise : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public static List<User> listuser = new List<User>()
   {
            new User() {ID = 1, UserName = "Dhruv", Password = "hello"},
            new User() {ID = 2, UserName = "Gaurav", Password = "12345"},
            new User() {ID = 3, UserName = "Rahul", Password = "asdfg"},
            new User() {ID = 4, UserName = "Guru", Password = "qwerty"}
   };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            listuser = new List<User>();
            GRIDDATA.DataSource = listuser;
            GRIDDATA.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        User data = new User();
        data.UserName = TextBox1.Text;
        data.Password = TextBox2.Text;
        //listuser.Add(data);

        bool UserExists(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            return listuser.Any(a => a.UserName.Equals(UserName) && a.Password.Equals(Password));
        }

        if(UserExists(data.UserName, data.Password))
        {

            Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://www.wwe.com");
        }
    }
}


public class User
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }   
}
}
```

Comment: The logic is somewhere wrong . Can't spot it. If statement not working but always else is getting executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Page_Load` should looks like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GRIDDATA.DataSource = listuser;
            GRIDDATA.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

and it **works fine**

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: if this answered your Question , could you mark this answer as answer 
thanks

Comment: oh sorry . Didn't knew about accept answer feature.